# mod_fastcgi.so + FCGI (perl) make 500 error with graceful restart on apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, perl, mod-fastcgi

We'd like to construct a perl (FCGI) application on apache2.2 with mod_fastcgi.so

but it makes 500 error when I graceful it.

Do you have any idea or solution for it?

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so
FastCgiIpcDir /va/tmp
FastCgiConfig -restart -singleThreshold 100
```

Comment: My first idea is "read the logs".

Comment: what is the entire error?

Answer (score 0):

When reporting an HTTP error code, always provide the relevant error from the ErrorLog. Otherwise it's guessing what might have happened :)

Another thing that might help, use mod_fcgid instead of mod_fastcgi. The latter is deprecated. 
For help with mod_fcgid see http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/

What might be causing a 500 Internal Server Error in your case:

- Putting these directives in a .htaccess instead of in the main configuration file
- Loading a non-existing, corrupted or wrong version of the fastcgi_module
- Providing a non-existant path to FastCgiIpcDir (you might mean /var/tmp/ instead of /va/tmp)